# Match the Date time param with key value

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I have two variables in the java-script like below.

```
const dbobj = {
    "id": "123-456",
  "dbtime": "2020-04-15T19:30:00.000z"
}

const userobj = {
    id: "123-456",
  usertime: {
    year: 2020,
    month: 04,
    day: 11,
    hour: 05,
    minute: 12
  }
}
```

With the above code I wish to check whether the date time from `dbobj` is getting match with `userobj.usertime` along with the ID as well.

I did it using the split feature of javascript.
But wish to know If any standard way available like using map or every function kind of.
Like somehow I can convert the `dbobj.dbtime` into epoch time and then I can match. Hope you got my point.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is probably the getTime() method because it returns the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch.

Because JavaScript uses milliseconds as the unit of measurement, whereas Unix Time is in seconds you can do the following:

```
const dbobj = {
    id: "123-456",
    dbtime: "2020-04-15T19:30:00.000z"
}

const userobj = {
    id: "123-456",
    usertime: {
        year: 2020,
        month: 04,
        day: 11,
        hour: 05,
        minute: 12
    }
}

const date1 = Math.round(new Date(dbobj.dbtime).getTime() / 1000);
const date2 = Math.round(new Date(userobj.usertime.year, userobj.usertime.month - 1, userobj.usertime.day, userobj.usertime.hour, userobj.usertime.minute).getTime() / 1000);

console.log(date1 > date2);
console.log(date1 < date2);
console.log(date1 === date2);
```

For more info, you can reference this article - [Date.prototype.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime).